# KeyNotFoundException register MvcCore in azure portal

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc

My web app deployed in azure gives the following error in the startup.

> KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>   This happens registering the MvcCore dependence.
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.get_Item(TKey key)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultAssemblyPartDiscoveryProvider+CandidateResolver.ComputeClassification(string
>   dependency)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultAssemblyPartDiscoveryProvider+CandidateResolver.ComputeClassification(string
>   dependency)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultAssemblyPartDiscoveryProvider+CandidateResolver+d__4.MoveNext()

In local environment run without problems. But in azure deploy throw that error.

```
services.AddMvcCore (options =>
{
  options.Filters.Add (new TelemetryActionFilter ());
});
```

Comment: What's your .net core version? I test it only change the startup and it works fine. Could you show me some reproduced code?

Comment: My .net core version is 1.1.1. The problem is when I deploy from Visual Studio everything works fine in azure, but when I do continuous deploy throw that error starting the app. I download the files from wwwroot using Kudu tool and deploy in my IIS local and work fine too and dont understand why in the azure platform dont work.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this? It's just started for me too.

Comment: We've started seeing it here too, when I upgraded our SF project from SF version 1.6 to 2.1. Also using .NET Core 1.1.1.